# Оборот разговорной речи

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Сколько смотрю на него, столько смеюсь" и "Сколько не смотрю на него, столько смеюсь". Как лучше сказать и уместна ли тут вообще частица "не"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разница в этих выражениях небольшая, но она есть. Второе предложение имеет более сильное интонационное подчеркивание в придаточной части, но, конечно, здесь должна быть частица НИ, а не частица НЕ. Придаточное предложение "сколько ни смотрю на него" является придаточным уступительным (отвечает на вопрос "несмотря на что?"), а в придаточных уступительных для утверждения используется частица НИ

Answer (score 3):

Первое предложение правильно. Второе будет правильным, если НЕ заменить на НИ. И местоимение я бы заменила. *Сколько НИ смотрю на него, все (время) смеюсь.*
В придаточном уступительном предложении с утвердительным значением пишется НИ. 
*Сколько НИ спрашивал, никто не ответил.* Спрашивал? Да. Пишу НИ (частица НИ в данном случае усиливает утверждение).